# setCells method sets four cells to a certain value instead of just one cell

Tags: java

So I'm making a Grid class. Here is my setCells method:

```
public boolean setCells(int rows[], int cols[], int vals[]) {
    if (rows.length == cols.length && cols.length == vals.length && vals.length == rows.length) {
        for (int i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols.length; j++) {
                for (int k = 0; k < vals.length; k++) {
                    setValue(rows[i], cols[j], vals[k]);

                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

And here's my client code:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int rows[] = {1,2};
    int columns[] = {1,2};
    int values[] = {1,2};

    Grid grid1 = new Grid(5, 7);
    Grid grid2 = new Grid(8);

    grid1.displayGrid();
    grid2.displayGrid();

    System.out.println(grid1.isEmpty());

    grid1.setCells(rows, columns, values);

    grid1.displayGrid();
```

Now whenever I use arrays with one element, the method works fine. However, when the arrays have more than one element, it sets four cells to that value instead of just one. Like this:

```
   0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   0  2  2  0  0  0  0
   0  2  2  0  0  0  0
   0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

It's supposed to look like this:

```
   0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   0  1  0  0  0  0  0
   0  0  2  0  0  0  0
   0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current algorithm has three nested loops, meaning that it attempts to set every possible combination of rows and columns to every listed value, rather than simply setting each cell once as desired. You only need one loop to iterate through a variable tracking index into all three arrays:

```
if (rows.length == cols.length && cols.length == vals.length) {
    for (int i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        setValue(rows[i], cols[i], vals[i]);
    }
}
```

Additionally, if you already know that rows and cols have the same lengths, and that cols and vals have the same lengths, then the third check (rows and vals have same length) is not necessary. I've removed it in the example code snippet directly preceding.